# For loop, how can I display each character on one single line

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop

```
var text = prompt("What is Lance trying to say"); 
//user type any text

for (var i = 0; i <= text.length; i++)
{
    var result = text.charAt(i);

    if (result == "e" || result == "o" || result == "a" || result == "u")
    {
        result = "i";
    }
    else if (result != "e")
    {
        result == result;
    }
    console.log(result);

}
```

result i have for now when user type "hello"

```
h

i

l

l

i
```

How can i get each single character on one line.

Comment: javascript, that's just an exercise from university. I cannot find a way to display every characters on one line

Comment: `<=` is not correct in `var i = 0; i <= text.length; i++`, you have to use `var i = 0; i < text.length; i++` for such usecase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that's what you want to achieve - that's without array join and push operations as request. Also I fixed `<=` in for loop; and `else if`doesn't make sense, just `else` is correct

```
var text = prompt("What is Lance trying to say"); 
//user type any text

var collect = '';

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    var result = text.charAt(i);

    if (result == "e" || result == "o" || result == "a" || result == "u") {
        collect += "i";
    } else {
        collect += result;
    }
}

console.log(collect);
```

Comment: thank you very much, what would be the simple code of collect += "i";

Comment: Sorry, didn't understood your question - you mean, what that code does? Variable `collect` starts as empty string, where we are collecting result. `collect += "i"` is just short form of `collect = collect + "i"`, which just appends `"i"` to the end of it.

Comment: yes that's exactly what i was looking for, thank you very much for your understanding. I'm new here, anything I need to do when you give the right answer ?

Comment: No prob, glad I could help and wish you luck with your studies. You should "accept" answer, that looks correct for you - there's a tick you can click and it turns green. In addition, you can use up arrows to give votes for all of those answers you find useful - but that's optional.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list to store the chars you want and join it :

```
  var text = prompt("What is Lance trying to say"); 
  //user type any text
  var char_list = [];

  for (var i = 0; i <= text.length; i++) {

    var result = text.charAt(i);

    if (result == "e" || result == "o" || result == "a" || result == "u") {
      char_list.push("i");
    }else if (result != "e") {
      char_list.push(result);
    }
  }

  console.log(char_list.join(''));
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but i cannot use join or push, i have to only use basic java script to do so, by adding a new string only

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few different approaches for comparison:

Using a series of if statements. Note the for statement uses a more compact syntax.

```
var text = prompt("What is Lance trying to say"); 
//user type any text

var result = "";
for (var i in text) {
    var ch = text.charAt(i);
    if (ch == "e" || ch == "o" || ch == "a" || ch == "u") {
        result = result + "i";        
    } else {
        result = result + ch;        
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Using a switch statement

```
var text = prompt("What is Lance trying to say"); 
//user type any text

var result = "";
for (var i in text) {
    var ch = text.charAt(i);
    switch (ch) {
        case "e": case "o": case "a": case "u":
            result = result + "i"
            break;
        default:
            result = result + ch;
            break;
    }
}
console.log(result)
```

Using regular expression and a ternary operator along with the += operator for appending values to a string

```
var text = prompt("What is Lance trying to say"); 
//user type any text

var result = '';

for (var i in text) {
    result += function(ch) {
        return ch.match(/[eoau]/) ? "i" : ch
    }(text.charAt(i));
}
console.log(result);
```

Good luck with your studies.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the letter each time, append the result to a single variable. Once the loop is finished then return the variable

Comment: that's exactly what i want to do but i cannot find the right way, I'm new to javascript

Comment: thank you for your answer but i cannot use join or push, i have to only use basic java script to do so, by adding a new string only